# Glue Python script to read xml (from SOAP) and write as Parquet to S3

Tags: python, pandas, soap, xml-parsing

I have a requirement to create a Glue Python script to read XML using SOAP API and store the returned xml string in Parquet format on S3.

I got the SOAP communication working fine. Now, for the later part, my intention was to create a `Pandas` `dataframe` by using `read_xml()` method with the returned XML string and then use the `df.to_parquet()` to store the xml in `parquet` format on `S3`.

Unfortunately, I am **unable** to parse the xml with `read_xml()`. Here is the code that I had created -

```
import requests
import xmltodict
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow

url = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx"

payload = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <soap12:Envelope 
                xmlns:xsi="http://w3.org/2002/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap12:Body>
          <CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com/xml/">
          <Celsius>20</Celsius>
          </CelsiusToFahrenheit>
        </soap12:Body>
       </soap12:Envelope>"""
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
result = xmltodict.parse(response.text)['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse']['CelsiusToFahrenheitResult']

print(f"The final result is : {result}")

df = pd.read_xml(response.text)

s3_url = 's3://bucket/folder/bucket.parquet'
df.to_parquet(s3_url)
```

When I run `print(df)` the following is returned -

Output:

```
CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse
0                       NaN
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xpath` argument in [pd.read_xml](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html)

```
df = pd.read_xml(response.text, xpath='.//xmlns:CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse', namespaces={'xmlns': 'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/'})
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   CelsiusToFahrenheitResult
0                         68
```

Comment: thank you. Is it possible to store the entire xml string that is returned, to parquet format on s3 using `pandas.to_parquet()`, instead of parsing it ? Perhaps from the pandas DF ? Any specific logic you'd agdvise ?

Comment: I don't know much about parquet, but I don't think it's possible to save entire xml using pandas to parquet

Comment: @marie20 it hardly makes any sense. A parquet file needs to have a schema of the actual data, whereas XML file is just string of bytes/characters if you don't parse it, so you'd just end up with a parquet file that has one string column inside it.

Comment: I think that would be fine. I only need to save the xml on S3. Once the parquet is saved another Python job would read this XML from s3 and parse it as per the requirements. Any advice on how to accomplish this ?